# MySQL : SELECT results from four different tables in one query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have four different tables, one main `SPECIAL` table containing only id's that reference to the `CONTRACT` and `PHONE` tables.

My query looks as follows:

```
SELECT *
FROM `specials` specials
INNER JOIN `contract` contracts
ON  specials.contract_id = contracts.id
INNER JOIN `phone` phones
ON specials.phone_id = phones.id
INNER JOIN `ugets` ugets
ON specials.id = ugets.special_id
```

At the moment, this only gets ONE row from the `UGETS` table, but I need all rows from this specific table with the correct `special_id`.

Can anyone please point me in the correct direction? I can't seem to help myself with Googling it.

Comment: What happens if you issue a simpler query - select * from specials inner join ugets on specials.id = ugets.special_id? How many rows do you get? Try not to use 'select *', especially with multi-table joins.

Comment: `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query looks about right, unless you also want all rows, regardless of the existence of a `contract` or `phone`. In this case, you'll want to use `OUTER JOIN` or `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN`:

```
SELECT *
FROM `specials` specials
LEFT JOIN `contract` contracts
ON  specials.contract_id = contracts.id
LEFT JOIN `phone` phones
ON specials.phone_id = phones.id
LEFT JOIN `ugets` ugets
ON specials.id = ugets.special_id
```

Fields from tables where there are not records for a given special will be returned with `NULL`, but all rows from tables where there's a match will be shown.

Beware this could have adverse performance impacts (possibly to the extent it voids the benefits of getting all four tables in a single query) - you should evaluate the gains vs. costs and see if you still want a single query.

Comment: Thank you, this works but it returns multiple rows for the two instances of `ugets` with the same `special_id`. I realize this is what LEFT JOIN is supposed to do, but is there a way in which instead of return multiple rows, it just returns an array value of the two `ugets` instances in the same row?

Comment: Looks like you're trying to get SQL to behave like a Turing-complete language. Some things are better done in application code, rather than DB-side. You might be able to achieve what you want using `GROUP_CONCAT`, but I would discourage against it (not portable, ...).

Comment: I opted for running a separate function to retrieve the values later on in my script. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 3):

INNER JOIN only returns rows where at least one match in both joined tables is available. The problem is that you are joining 4 tables together. So there could be more records (than 1) if you join only specials with ugets but these records get filtered out if you join with your other tables.

If it is not necessary that there is an existing record for every specials-entry in phones or contracts then change the joining type for these 2 tables to left join. (as unspecific hinted by comment of Dr. biziclop)

In general you should consider which of your joined data is optional and which is required. Your example query requires all data of your tables. Maybe this is not what you intended.

Comment: So, I gather, INNER JOIN will not return two or more rows from `UGET` if both of them have the same `special_id` that corresponds to an `id` in the `SPECIAL` table.

Comment: If you only inner join SPECIAL with UGET then you should receive every  possible combination of records in SPECIAL and UGET according to your joining condition. That means that records in UGET with an identical field value of special_id will result in separate records in your result set. IF you want them to be limited to only one join per special_id in SPECIALS then you have to group your records (this will limit your selectable columns to grouped or aggregated ones) or you determine a UGET id having this special_id within a subquery and add a condition to match against that id.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to LEFT JOINing, you could consider using UNION ALL to join the results of three queries, each inner joining the `specials` table to one of the other three tables.

This will ensure that you only return n(1)+n(2)+n(3) rows for each row on the `specials` table, instead of n(1)*n(2)*n(3) rows.